# Deserializing callback of non-field element

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I have the following XML structure:

```
<key>
   <element>
      someValue
   </element>

   <!-- lots of other elements which should be deserialized into the class -->

   <other>
      someOtherValue
   </other>
</key>
```

And i use [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to deserialize it to the following Java class:

```
@Root(name = "key", strict = false)
public class Key {

    @Element(name = "element")
    private String element;

    // lots of more fields should be deserialized from xml
}
```

Note that the class does not have a field for the `other` element. I do not need the value of it in the class, but in an other place. How can i intercept the parsing and extract the value of this `other` element?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a number of ways, best is to use a [Converter](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter.html) or a [Strategy](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/strategy/Strategy.html) though. Converter is the easiest of the two.

Comment: Thank you! My bad, maybe the OP was misleading. I edited it. My problem is that the `Key` class has lots of fields, and i want to use default deserialization on these, and extract the extra element in a custom manner. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you got any more tips? :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Strategy` approach doesn't work, because they use the annotated class as the XML schema, and what is not present in the schema that will not be processed (visitors can't visit).

Converters can be used as follows:

```
@Root(name = "key", strict = false)
@Convert(KeyConverter.class)
public class Key {

    private String element;

    public Key(String elementValue) {
        element = elementValue;
    }
```

}

The converter stores the value during conversion:

```
public class KeyConverter implements Converter<Key> {

    private String otherValue;

    @Override
    public Key read(InputNode node) throws Exception {
        String elementValue = node.getNext("element").getValue().trim();
        otherValue = node.getNext("other").getValue().trim();
        return new Key(elementValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode arg0, Key arg1) throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * @return the otherValue
     */
    public String getOtherValue() {
        return otherValue;
    }
```

}

Putting together:

```
    Registry registry = new Registry();

    KeyConverter keyConverter = new KeyConverter();
    registry.bind(Key.class, keyConverter);

    Persister serializer = new Persister(new RegistryStrategy(registry));
    Key key = serializer.read(Key.class, this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("key.xml"));
    // Returns the value "acquired" during the last conversion
    System.out.println(keyConverter.getOtherValue());
```

This is not too elegant, but might be suitable for your need.

Comment: Thanks! My OP was a little bit misleading. :( This is just a reduced example, actually the `Key` class contains lots of other fields. Is there any way to invoke the default converter on the class fields, and just use this on the extra element? I edited to OP.

Comment: @WonderCsabo do you have the possibility to change the XML schema? For instance, putting the value of `other` in an attribute of the element `key`

Comment: Unfortunately not. The xml comes from an unmodifiable interface, if we would change it, other old code would break. :( Yeah, i know this schema is not designed well.

Answer (score 0):

I could not make a solution with a `Stragegy` or `Converter` as **ng** and **Katona** suggested. However, i made a workaround, which works, but not too nice.

```
/* package */ class SerializedKey extends Key {

    @Element(name = "other", required = false)
    private int mOtherValue;

    public int getOtherValue() {
        return mOtherValue;
    }
}

...

Serializer serializer = new Persister();
SerializedKey key = serializer.read(SerializedKey.class, mInputStream);
int otherValue = key.getOtherValue();
```

Outside of the serialization package, i use `Key` as static type, so i simply *forget* that another field is in that object. When i persist my data, i also persist as a `Key`, so the `mOtherValue` is not connected to the class anymore. As you can see `SerializedKey` class is package-private, so i do not expose this helper class to any other component of my application.